# Couldn't deduce template parameter from function parameter's default argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to make a function which finds the minimum element in a range which satisfies a given condition:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename It, typename Pred, typename Comp>
It minElementWhere(
    It begin,
    It end,
    Pred pred = Pred(),

    // Use less-than as the default comparator.
    Comp comp = std::less<decltype(*std::declval<It>())>()
) {
    It minElement = end;

    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (!pred(*it)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (comp(*it, *minElement)) {
            minElement = it;
        }
    }

    return minElement;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<double> foo;
    foo.push_back(6);
    foo.push_back(10);
    foo.push_back(-3);
    foo.push_back(7);

    std::cout << *minElementWhere(
        foo.begin(),
        foo.end(),
        [](double val) {
            return val >= 0;
        }
    ) << std::endl;
}
```

But I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:40:5: error: no matching function for call to 'minElementWhere(std::vector<double>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator, main()::__lambda0)'
     ) << std::endl;
     ^
main.cpp:40:5: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:6:4: note: template<class It, class Pred, class Comp> It minElementWhere(It, It, Pred, Comp)
 It minElementWhere(
    ^
main.cpp:6:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:40:5: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'Comp'
     ) << std::endl;
```

`Comp` isn't the return type, so it's not trying to deduce the return type, and it doesn't seem to me like there are ambiguous overloads of `Comp` (since there can only be one return type of dereferencing an `It`). Why am I getting this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's not possible to deduce template parameters from defaulted arguments.

Comment: [OT]: your implementation is UB as you do `comp(*it, *end)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're expecting the template parameter `Comp` to be deduced from the default argument you provided for the corresponding function parameter. However, this is explicitly listed as a non-deduced context, meaning template argument deduction will fail for that template parameter (unless it can be deduced from elsewhere).

From *§14.8.2.5/5 [temp.deduct.type]*

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>   — ... 
>  
>   — A template parameter used in the parameter type of a
>   function parameter that has a default argument that is being used in
>   the call for which argument deduction is being done.

To have template argument deduction succeed, provide a default argument for the template parameter, instead of the function parameter.

```
template <typename It, 
          typename Pred, 
          typename Comp = std::less<decltype(*std::declval<It>())>>
It minElementWhere(
    It begin,
    It end,
    Pred pred = Pred(),
    Comp comp = Comp()
) {
...
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ffa9d6178cf10ddb)

Answer (score 3):

You may want the following:

```
#include <iterator>
struct always_true{
    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(T&& val) const{
        return true;
    }
};

template <
    typename It, 
    typename Pred = always_true,
    typename Comp = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type >
>
It minElementWhere(
    It begin,
    It end,
    Pred pred = Pred(),
    Comp comp = Comp()
    ){
    It minElement = end;

    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (pred(*it) && (minElement == end || comp(*it, *minElement))){
            minElement = it;
        }
    }

    return minElement;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
template <typename It, typename Pred,
          typename Comp = std::less<decltype(*std::declval<It>())>>
It minElementWhere(
    It begin,
    It end,
    Pred pred = Pred(),
    Comp comp = Comp()
) {
    It minElement = end;

    for (It it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        if (!pred(*it)) {
            continue;
        }

        if (comp(*it, *minElement)) {
            minElement = it;
        }
    }

    return minElement;
}
```